# Python: Parse wordpress HTML

Tags: python, wordpress

I am trying to build a blog-mapping site, which would spot the current trends in a given set of blogs. For convenience, I'm going to focus on a given list of Wordpress blogs.

Is there a Python package for parsing Wordpress HTML?

I'm looking for:

- Identification (Is the given HTML a Wordpress blog)
- Blog properties (name, posts, rss link, blogroll...)
- Post properties (title, text, tags...)

If there is no such package, I can implement it myself as an Open Source project, but an existing one would save me lots of time.

Comment: If you write your own, look at [beautiful soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Comment: I suggest lxml as more modern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I know, there are not any parsing libraries that parse WordPress HTML specially, but general-purpose HTML parsing libraries such as [html5lib](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/), [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

I recommend you [html5lib+`lxml.html`](http://lxml.de/html5parser.html).